# Android textview text with two different sizes

Tags: java, android, textview, android-textattributes

Im trying to set html text with different text sizes in one textview but nothing.

I'm trying like this:

```
textViewNextTime.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>4</h2><p>38</p>"));
```

and also I've tried using  and  tags but without success. Can anyone help me to create a textView with text like this(without the circle ofcourse):

[image]

**Edit:** In example the `4` should be like `140sp` in size, and the `:38` should be something like `70sp` in size

Comment: Please explain what "without success" means. For example, you might take screenshots of what you are getting and post them. Beyond that, your HTML will not give you what you are seeking in a regular Web browser either, as the `4` and the `38` will be on separate lines. You will have better luck, in browsers and with `Html.fromHtml()`, if you use `<font size="...">` instead of `<h2>` and `<p>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to use html you can try something like this:

```
String s= "4:38";
SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(s);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 1, 0); // set size
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText(ss1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String htmlText = "<body><h1>Heading Text</h1><p>This tutorial " +
            "explains how to display " +
            "<strong>HTML </strong>text in android text view.&nbsp;</p>" +
            "<img src=\"hughjackman.jpg\">" +
            "<blockquote>Example from <a href=\"www.javatechig.com\">" +
            "Javatechig.com<a></blockquote></body>";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView htmlTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.html_text);
        htmlTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText, new ImageGetter(), null));

    }

    private class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {

        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            int id;
            if (source.equals("hughjackman.jpg")) {
                id = R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }

            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
            d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return d;
        }
    };

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your HTML text Below"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/html_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```